# Using Binomial formula, random variable x probability

Tags: statistics

Here is the question.

From past records, a clothing store finds that 55% of the people who enter the store will make a purchase.  During a one hour period, 20 people enter the store. The random variable x represents the number of people who make the purchase.

Find the probability that :

1. Exactly seven people make a purchase (use the binomial formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${20 \choose 7} (.55)^7 (.45)^{20-7}$

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: it's only about 7 seconds :)

Comment: I missed this lesson in class so I don't know what the binomial formula is, I have to show all the work and I'm not sure how to lay out the formula.  There's 7 questions based off the "story"  but figured if I could see how the first question is answered then I could answer the other 6 myself

Comment: @Sasha did you figure out the others? Feel free to post other questions, many people are willing to help if needed.

Comment: Yes I did! Or at least I think so haha

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what the binomial theorem is?? You have all the info you need..

20 choose 7

Probability of success (p) = .55

Probability of failure (q) = .45